# using for loops to camel case a phrase

Tags: objective-c, loops, nsstring

I have to lowercase the letter of the first string, remove the space and capitalized the rest of the phrase. So my output should look like from:

This is america -> thisIsAmerica

Apple macbook -> appleMacbook

supercalifragalisticexpialidocious -> stays the same

I am able to get as far as removing the spaces and capitalizing the letters and then using a for loop to get the index 0 and trying to lowercase it but it does not seem to be working. My code is as follows:

```
#import "CaseMaker.h"

@implementation CaseMaker
- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.camelString = string;
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)process {
    NSString * output = [[NSString alloc] init];


    for (int i = 0; [_camelString length]; i++) {
        NSString *iChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [_camelString characterAtIndex:0]];
        [[iChar lowercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];
    }
    output = [[_camelString capitalizedString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

return output;

}

@end
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a mutable array.
- Make an array form the input string by separating the items by space characters.
- If there are no spaces in the string return the string lowercased.
- Make the first item lowercased and add it to the output array.
- Iterate the components starting with index 1, capitalize all objects and add them to the output array.
- Finally join the array by empty string and return the result.

---

```
-(NSString *)process {
    NSMutableArray<NSString *> * output = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray<NSString *> *components = [camelString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    if (components.count < 2) { return camelString.lowercaseString; }
    [output addObject:components[0].lowercaseString];
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < components.count; ++i) {
        [output addObject:components[i].capitalizedString];
    }
    return [output componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this worked! However, I am a little unsure of the purpose of the <> brackets. what are they used for in this case. Do they turn the mutable arrays and arrays into strings?

Comment: No, it's an addition to be able to specify strong typed collection types. For example `NSArray<NSString *>` means an array containing only strings. Without the generic type `components[0].lowercaseString` doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, *...means an array containing only strings*. 

Comment: Just one more thing, what is the purpose of components.count < 2?

Comment: If the array contains less than two items you can skip the loop because there is only one string without spaces. The loop starts with 1 because the item at index 0 becomes lowercased before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps:

1. Use the function `componentsSeparatedByString:` to split the string at the spaces. The result is an array with the separated words. It should look something like this:

   `NSArray *wordsArray = [camelString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];`
2. Loop over the array and apply upper- or lowercase to each string, similar to what you already  did.

   `[[iChar lowercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];`
3. Concatenate the strings in the array to one string again

I hope it is no problem to write the code following these steps.